# Google CardDAV API Authentication

Tags: google-api

Is there a way to authenticate to an accounts' contacts with a saved token? In my research it looks like you have to create a new token by having the user login and give consent.

Thank you,

Brandon

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.
Make sure you include `access_type=offline` in your authentication request. After a user gives your app the permission for the first time a `Refresh Token` will be present in the response. If you save it, you can use it later to get a new `Access Token` every time you need it. No consent screen will be shown.

Although you can craft your own auth mechanism, Google provides a nice [set of client libraries](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#libraries), which will do all the work for you (exchanging Refresh Token for an Access Token, getting a new Refresh Token after it has expired, ...).